# Initial state of checkbox?

Tags: angularjs

Running this code by clicking checkbox returns `true` or `false` for `{{isHidden}}` as expected. But when the code is run for the very first time `{{isHidden}}` appear to be blank. How to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Hidden: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isHidden">{{isHidden}}
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: assign `true` or `false` to the `isHidden` inside controller

Comment: it doesn't have a controller yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-init` directive

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isHidden" ng-init="isHidden= true">{{isHidden}}
```

use true or false in `ng-init` it will initialize the values on a scope

here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/emNCrHLBVzfYtEvgOxcR?p=preview)